# SQL taking so long time to update the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just updating one of the SQL table by using a simple update query (just 5 records), it's running so long time and not results.

Please help me out.

```
UPDATE ETL_Phone_Number 
SET 
status_flag = 'N' 
WHERE 
status_flag = 'P';
```

Table create Query:

```
create table ETL_Phone_Number_Updated
(
CRM_ID  varchar2 (250),
Addr_Hash_Key   varchar2(250),
Phone_Number varchar2 (250),
status varchar2 (250),
status_flag varchar2 (250)
)
```

Comment: Do you have an uncommitted update active in another window perhaps?

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: Just 5 records.

Comment: What is the output of the following query: `select *
from v$session
where sid in (select session_id from dba_dml_locks where  name = 'ETL_PHONE_NUMBER ');`

Comment: Its just executed with no data , only fields info came out.

Comment: Can you please change the name of the table in `where name = 'ETL_PHONE_NUMBER'` with correct table name and execute the query?

Comment: Yes.. Tejash. "ETL_Phone_Number" is my table and  UPDATE ETL_Phone_Number 
SET 
status_flag = 'N' 
WHERE 
status_flag = 'P';

Comment: select * from v$session where sid in (select session_id from dba_dml_locks where name = 'ETL_Phone_Number_Updated');  execute this

Comment: Hi Tahir.. thank you. I have executed but its not resulting any data only fields info.

Comment: `select * from v$session where sid in (select session_id from dba_dml_locks where upper(name) = upper('ETL_Phone_Number_Updated')`

Answer (score 1):

It may have blocked the labels, so you need to free up some spaces. You can use this basic syntax for killing a session:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

Kindly also refer this link if it doesn't work: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions

Answer (score 0):

Please try to kill all your sessions related to this table and try again.

Comment: Hi Tahir, can u share the query or some more inf to kill session related to this table

Comment: -- find session id
select session_id,sqltext.text
 from sys.dm_exec_requests 
 cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)sqltext    and then using kill keyword, kill that sessin id

Answer (score 0):

the most probable thing causing such a behaviour could be an another session trying to alter the data within the table without committing it.

In order to find it out who has blocked the object ask the database for the following.

```
select s.sid, s.serial# 
  from dba_locks l,
       all_objects o,
       v$session s
 where l.lock_id1 = o.object_id
   and l.session_id = s.SID
   and o.object_name = upper('ETL_Phone_Number');
```

Then if there were rows returned, perform the following command
    alter system kill session 'sid, serial#' immediate;

The last statement will kill the sessions and will release the table for update